# WP_Query offset argument does not work

Tags: posts, wp-query, offsets

I want to display all posts starting from a certain offset, my query is:

```
WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'offset'            => 20,
    'cat'               => 5,
) );
```

This query shows all posts without starting from the offset value. Whys is that?

Comment: What happens if you do `posts_per_page=200`?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Works properly. But why not work with a value of `-1` ?

Comment: See my answer, you may also try using `nopaging => true` or `paged => 1` to see if that also works with offset and your -1 value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `offset` index for WP_Query generally works with pagination. When you set pagination to a `-1` the function assumes you're getting all posts and there will be no pagination or offset. So to counteract this you would set the `posts_per_page` to a high number like 999. Reading the [Function Reference on WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) the pagination section says:

> `'posts_per_page'=>-1` to show all posts (**the `'offset'` parameter is ignored with a -1 value**). Set the ‘paged’ parameter if pagination is off after using this parameter.